# Ruby on Rails how to process the JSON Array which doesnt have a name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I want to have a create endpoint which gets a JSONArray and creates more than one Coordinate objects (it has 2 attributes latitude and longitude) but the problem is my sample JSONArray doesn't have a name tag. How can I declare that create requires this kind of JSOnArray, iterate over this JSONArray and access the data?

EXAMPLE JSON

```
[{ "latitude": 32.9377784729004, "longitude": -117.230392456055 },
{ "latitude": 32.937801361084, "longitude": -117.230323791504 },
{ "latitude": 32.9378204345703, "longitude": -117.230278015137 },
{ "latitude": 32.9378204345703, "longitude": -117.230239868164 },
{ "latitude": 32.9378318786621, "longitude": -117.230209350586 },
{ "latitude": 32.9378814697266, "longitude": -117.230102539062 },
{ "latitude": 32.9378890991211, "longitude": -117.230072021484 },
{ "latitude": 32.9379081726074, "longitude": -117.230018615723 },
{ "latitude": 32.9379005432129, "longitude": -117.22998046875 },
{ "latitude": 32.937931060791, "longitude": -117.229949951172 },
{ "latitude": 32.9379615783691, "longitude": -117.229919433594 }]
```

Thats how the classes look like

```
class Trace < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :gps_coordinates
end
```

```
class GpsCoordinate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trace
end
```

and my Migrations

```
class CreateTraces < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :traces do |t|
      t.string :gps_coordinates
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateGpsCoordinates < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :gps_coordinates do |t|
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude

      t.references :trace, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and what I am trying to do as a code would be

```
def create
    trace1 = Trace.create();
    params[].each do |latitude, longitude|
      GpsCoordinate.create!(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, trace_id: trace1.id())
    end

    render json: trace1, status: :created

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    render json: e.message, status: 501
  end
```

but I dont know how can I declare that I am going to get a JSONArray to the end point so I can iterate over it and how to iterate without a name.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking. If the array is the root of the json you don’t need to access it by name.

Comment: I need to get that JSONArray over my create endpoint and read the elements out of it. I have been searching since yesterday but couldn't find how can I iterate over this array and access the data. All other solutions were using a name tag and when I do the same without a name tag it just doesn't work. I am quite new in Ruby on Rails. I am trying to understand.

Comment: Maybe showing some actual code would help.

Comment: alright I am editing now thank you :)

Comment: I hope now it is more clear what I am trying to do

Comment: "That" JSON array meaning what? What's `params`? `params[]` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I posted an example JSONArray on the top I am trying to send it to localhost/trace via Postman and I need a create endpoint which can process that data and I dont know how thats the question I checked out how the other people iterate over arrays but they use paramater names to iterate over so I tried to iterate without a name since my paramater doesnt have a name. Last code is not a finished code. My question is actually how to make this def create.

Comment: Why not just put a `binding.pry` (or equivalent) in the `create` method and see what `params` contains?

Comment: thank you apparently its called "_json" now I will try to iterate over that

Comment: I solved it thank you :)

Comment: Excellent :) Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your create route is a POST and that you're delivering the JSON data via the POST request body, you should be able to access it with `request.body` and use the `each` method to iterate over it.

Comment: Thank you it also works but I solved it with params["_json"].each do |trace|